# Laravel get the posts which is not liked by the user

Tags: mysql, laravel, join

I have 3 tables in mysql. "users", "posts" and "likes". The "likes" table has user_id and post_id. I can get the posts which is liked by a certain user by this code in Laravel:

```
$posts = Post::join('likes', function($join) use($userId) {
    $join->on('likes.user_id', '=', $userId);
    $join->on('likes.post_id', '=', 'posts.id'));
});
$posts->select('posts.*');
```

But I want a query to get all of the posts which is not liked by that user.

Comment: Could you attach your models?

Comment: @V-K Assume that "Post" has one column (id) and "User" has one column (id) and "Like" has three columns (id, user_id, post_id)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$posts = Post::whereDoesntHave('likes', function (Builder $query) use($userId) {
              $query->where('user_id', $userId);
           });
```

If you have all relationships inside your models, you can use `whereDoesntHave` function.

Comment: just `Post::whereDoesntHave`... no need for `query()` or the undefined constant `query` you have there

Comment: I know, just use it because of `PHPStorm` works well with it